# MongoDB how to access pre existing collections?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

If I already have some collections with some data then how to access them without knowing the "Schema" of those collections? Because when I try to define schema for those collection it gives me error `"Cannot overwrite model once compiled Mongoose"`.

Someone suggested this so this is what I'm trying to do.

```
mongoose.model("post", new Schema({}), "posts");
```

But still I'm getting errors, someone also suggested this method.

```
const connection = await mongoose.connect("..");
connection.db.collection("posts").find({});
```

This gives me error "property collection doesn't exist".

I'm stuck and don't know how to access pre-existing collections.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Do you have access to your mongodb terminal?

Comment: Why is that? I mean I'm trying to connect using ```mongoose.connect```.